# the type of the expression must be an array type but is resolved to char

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, char, tile

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Sheet extends JFrame{
    private String[] line = {
    "wwwwwwffwwwwww",       
    "wwwwwwfffffffw",       
    "wwwwwwffwwwffw",       
    "wwwwwwffwwwffw",
    "wwwwwwfffffffw",
    "wwwwwwffwwwwww"        
    };
    String line1 = "wwwwwffwwwww";
            int tileX =50;
    int tileY= 50;
    public Sheet(){
        //setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setResizable(false);
        setTitle("window");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sheet frame = new Sheet();

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0,100,1000,1);
        for(int i = 0; i<line.length; i++){
            for(int f = 0; f<line[i].length(); f++){
                char line = line[f].charAt(i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code, I am trying to make a program that draws tiles according to an array of strings. In this paint method, I have 2 for loops, one to cycle through the array index for the lines, and one to cycle through the characters of the array. I get this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to char

```
at Sheet.paint(Sheet.java:36)
```

Please could someone help me fix this? I have tried with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hey, I added Java tag for you so the Java experts will come over. =)

Comment: Remember to check for compilation errors before running your program.   If you're using Eclipse, it's handy to keep the "Problems" tab view visible while you're developing.  If there are any errors in the problems tab, fix them before running.  You'll save yourself some headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to redeclare the `line` variable. Change the variable name and you should be fine:

```
char c = line[f].charAt(i);
```

It's a fairly obscure error message, because by the time the compiler's understood that you're declaring a variable of type `char` with name `line`, when it looks at the initializer it sees `line[f]` and thinks that's crazy. The fact that the variable wouldn't even be assigned a *value* at that point is just another problem :)